# CollectionViewCell is displaying the wrong image when I scroll fast

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I know people have asked this question before but the way I implemented my code seems a tad different because I'm using cell tags. I'm really happy with how everything is loading OTHER then when I scroll too fast the images jitter and are out of place. How can I solve this issue?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PageCell", for: indexPath)

        if let activity = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
            activityMain.isHidden = true
            activityMain.stopAnimating()
            activity.isHidden = false
            activity.startAnimating()

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let pageLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
            pageLabel.text = self.Networking.fetchedPagesNumbers.reversed()[indexPath.row]
            }
        }

        if let image = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UIImageView {

            image.image = UIImage(named: "Rectangle")

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                do{
                    let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string:self.Networking.fetchedPagesURLs.reversed()[indexPath.row])!)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)!

                        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: self.Networking.fetchedPagesURLs.reversed()[indexPath.row] as NSString )

                        image.image = imageToCache

                            if let activity = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
                                activity.isHidden = true
                                activity.stopAnimating()
                                collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
                            }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    // error
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Instead of tags

```
if let activity = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
```

create`IBOutlet` for every UI element inside the cell custom class with casting the cell

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PageCell", for: indexPath) 
 as! PageCell
```

2- No need for `DispatchQueue.main.async` in

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 if let pageLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
```

as code of `cellForRowAt` runs by default inside main queue

3- Instead of doing the heavy work of image download.cache use
[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:self.Networking.fetchedPagesURLs.reversed()[indexPath.row])!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: Fixed it! Just from this post I've learned a lot from you. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: This could be the answer, but I think it is better that you have to explain why the collection view display wrong image.

Comment: @dduyduong  From my understanding, when I scroll from cell to cell I make a network request to a url that's stored in an array. Depending on the row of the index path of that cell, the corresponding element should be displaying the appropriate image. Cells in my collection view are being reused, because of this, when I scroll fast the image that is pulled from the array a few cells ago is being displayed on the currently viewed cell instead of the cell it originally was loading on.

Comment: @B.Harrison yes that's it

Comment: @Sh_Khan Same problem here with different code structure. What change solves the noted problem? Number 3, so the use of SDWebImage instead of download.cache / NSCACHE?

Answer (score 3):

In collectionViewCell class, you should override prepareForReuse()

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.pageLabel.text = nil
    self.imageView.image = UIImage()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to image caching, I would recommend **Kingfisher**: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

It's very easy to use:

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the help! I was able to achieve my desired result by using **SDWebImage**. Do you recommend using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)  instead of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)? If so, why?